# Statsmodels: difficulty overlaying ARIMA forecast with confidence bounds on original data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, statsmodels, arima

I have some stock data, downloaded and made into a pandas series via

```
import quandl as qd
api =  '1uRGReHyAEgwYbzkPyG3'
qd.ApiConfig.api_key = api 

data = qd.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', qopts={'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'close']},
                    ticker=['AMZN'], date={'gte': '2000-01-01', 'lte': '2014-03-10'})

data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

price = pd.Series(data.iloc[:,2].values,index=pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:,1]))
```

And with statsmodels, I want to graph an ARIMA model showing the following:

1. the original data,
2. the fitted values overlapping some original data, and
3. the future forecast + confidence interval up to specified distance.

[image]

The picture above comes from the statsmodels documentation [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.plot_predict.html), but following their code throws me weird errors.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = price.loc['2012-01-03':].plot(ax=ax, label='observed')

fig = model_fit.plot_predict('2014-01-03','2015-01-03', dynamic=False, ax=ax, plot_insample=False)

plt.show()
```

Error below,

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1420243200000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1420243200000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in _get_predict_end(self, end)
    172             try:
--> 173                 end = self._get_dates_loc(dates, dtend)
    174             except KeyError as err: # end is greater than dates[-1]...probably

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in _get_dates_loc(self, dates, date)
     94     def _get_dates_loc(self, dates, date):
---> 95         date = dates.get_loc(date)
     96         return date

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1425             key = Timestamp(key, tz=self.tz)
-> 1426             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1427 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-206-505c74789333> in <module>()
      3 ax = price.loc['2012-01-03':].plot(ax=ax, label='observed')
      4 
----> 5 fig = model_fit.plot_predict('2014-01-03','2015-01-03', dynamic=False, ax=ax, plot_insample=False)
      6 
      7 plt.show()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in plot_predict(self, start, end, exog, dynamic, alpha, plot_insample, ax)
   1885 
   1886         # use predict so you set dates
-> 1887         forecast = self.predict(start, end, exog, 'levels', dynamic)
   1888         # doing this twice. just add a plot keyword to predict?
   1889         start = self.model._get_predict_start(start, dynamic=dynamic)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in predict(self, start, end, exog, typ, dynamic)
   1808     def predict(self, start=None, end=None, exog=None, typ='linear',
   1809                 dynamic=False):
-> 1810         return self.model.predict(self.params, start, end, exog, typ, dynamic)
   1811     predict.__doc__ = _arima_results_predict
   1812 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in predict(self, params, start, end, exog, typ, dynamic)
   1184             if not dynamic:
   1185                 predict = super(ARIMA, self).predict(params, start, end, exog,
-> 1186                                                      dynamic)
   1187 
   1188                 start = self._get_predict_start(start, dynamic)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in predict(self, params, start, end, exog, dynamic)
    732         # will return an index of a date
    733         start = self._get_predict_start(start, dynamic)
--> 734         end, out_of_sample = self._get_predict_end(end, dynamic)
    735         if out_of_sample and (exog is None and self.k_exog > 0):
    736             raise ValueError("You must provide exog for ARMAX")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in _get_predict_end(self, end, dynamic)
   1062         Handling of inclusiveness should be done in the predict function.
   1063         """
-> 1064         end, out_of_sample = super(ARIMA, self)._get_predict_end(end, dynamic)
   1065         if 'mle' not in self.method and not dynamic:
   1066             end -= self.k_ar

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in _get_predict_end(self, end, dynamic)
    673     def _get_predict_end(self, end, dynamic=False):
    674         # pass through so predict works for ARIMA and ARMA
--> 675         return super(ARMA, self)._get_predict_end(end)
    676 
    677     def geterrors(self, params):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in _get_predict_end(self, end)
    177                     freq = self.data.freq
    178                     out_of_sample = datetools._idx_from_dates(dates[-1], dtend,
--> 179                                             freq)
    180                 else:
    181                     if freq is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/datetools.py in _idx_from_dates(d1, d2, freq)
    100     return len(DatetimeIndex(start=_maybe_convert_period(d1),
    101                              end=_maybe_convert_period(d2),
--> 102                              freq=_freq_to_pandas[freq])) - 1
    103 
    104 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    116                 else:
    117                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 118             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    119         return wrapper
    120     return _deprecate_kwarg

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in __new__(cls, data, freq, start, end, periods, copy, name, tz, verify_integrity, normalize, closed, ambiguous, dtype, **kwargs)
    303 
    304         if data is None and freq is None:
--> 305             raise ValueError("Must provide freq argument if no data is "
    306                              "supplied")
    307 

ValueError: Must provide freq argument if no data is supplied
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

After Chad Fulton's suggestions, I attempted A) downloading the data with the frequency already pre-specified, B) changing the frequency manually of the original data after downloading, and C) updating statsmodels to 0.9 and retrying all the above.

A gives me the error "Inferred frequency None from passed dates does not conform to passed frequency D", whereas B produces `NaN`'s in the data that cause the model itself not to run, and C changes the error types for B.

I think what's going on is that since no frequency can be applied to the data, the forecast is not to blame for not knowing how to generate future dates. In that case, does anybody have any practical advice on how to utilize as much data as possible for a financial time series when doing basic forecasting, at least for non-state space models that automatically deal with missing data?

Answer (score 1):

My first answer, which is maybe not so satisfying but is probably better in the long run, is the suggestion that you upgrade to Statsmodels 0.9, which has overhauled date/time handling. That is more than likely to solve your problem.

My second answer is that you can probably solve your problem with Statsmodels < 0.9 by making sure your date index has a frequency. It's looks like your dates might be daily (if not, you'll have to change the below to use the right `freq` argument), so I suggest that you replace:

`price = pd.Series(data.iloc[:,2].values,index=pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:,1]))`

with:

`price = pd.Series(data.iloc[:,2].values, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(data.iloc[:,1], freq='D'))`

Comment: Enacting your second answer first (to explore the principle behind the problem) unfortunately gives the error "Inferred frequency None from passed dates does not conform to passed frequency D". Also, after myself trying to finagle the `DatetimeIndex` to either the Daily or Business frequency, I find that I inevitably get some `NaN`'s, but then if I drop them, the index loses the `freq` characteristic. So the dilemma is choosing one of two errors: A) with no frequency, perform time series analysis without date information, or B) with frequency, have ARIMA not run because of the missing values.

Comment: After updating statsmodels to 0.9, the problem still remains, with a new error. The first is "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable", and the last on the bottom (after a lot more text) is "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2014-01-03'". 

After confirming, the same dynamic exists as before, either I cannot use dates, or I cannot run the time series analysis :( .